# Require cookie to view website, or be redirected to different page (PHP)

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

Simple request; I need visitors to my site to have a certain cookie to view the website. When user goes to ***my.site.com/anydirectory/anypage.php*** they need to be redirected to ***my.site.com/index.php*** where they are given a warning and a choice to **Walk Away** or **Continue**. If they Continue, a cookie is set and they are take to the originally requested page (and ultimately have access to the whole site, for at least 90 days). If they choose to Walk Away then a different cookie is set and they are redirected to ***my.site.com/bummer.php***, and will continue to be directed to the **bummer.php** page until 90 days is up or they delete the cookie, whichever comes first.

Here is what I have;

I placed this at the top of all of my pages...

```
<?php if (!isset($_COOKIE['youwerewarned'])) {
header("Location: /index.php?url=http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]")
}
?>
```

...then I placed this at the top of my **index.php** page...

```
<?php

// change to your domain name.
$domain = "my.site.com";

// Get the requested page, add it to our domain so we can create an enter link
if (isset($_GET['request'])) {
$request ="<a href='http://$domain" . $_GET['request'] . "'>";
}

// The exit link
{
$leave ="<a href='http://my.site.com/bummer.php'>";
}

// Set a cookie so we are not redirected back here again. You can set how long the cookie is good.
if (!isset($_COOKIE['youwerewarned'])) {
setcookie('youwerewarned','true',time()+6048... . $domain);
}

?>
```

...then I placed this in the **index.php** page in the appropriate place...

```
<?php echo $leave ?>WALK AWAY</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $request ?>CONTINUE</a>
```

...what am I missing?

Comment: and this isn't working HOW? Did you check if the cookies actually get set? Perhaps you've got a premature headers-sent problem.

Comment: *"what am I missing?"* - A semi-colon for the header. Having [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on, would signal `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'in...` **IF** that is your actual working code and not just a copy/paste error.

Answer (score 0):

Far as I can tell, you're missing a closing/ending semi-colon for:

```
header("Location: /index.php?url=http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]")
```

do:

```
header("Location: /index.php?url=http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
```

Then there's this line which I don't know if this => `... .` is part of your actual code or not.

```
setcookie('youwerewarned','true',time()+6048... . $domain);
```

which should read as

```
setcookie("youwerewarned", "true", time()+6048, "/", $domain);
```

---

Having [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on, would signal

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in...(path to file) on line X

for the missing semi-colon.

Comment: Thank you, I am wondering, besides the errors, is everything where it is supposed to be?

Comment: @RickSmalls You're welcome Rick. I believe so, I tested the code and it worked fine. `var_dump($_COOKIE);` did show up as being just that, the cookie's name.

Comment: It is working, kinda. The 

`<?php echo $leave ?>WALK AWAY</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $request ?>CONTINUE</a>`

links are not working. The **Continue** does not work at all and when you click on **Walk Away** it should set a totally different cookie. When it redirects to the index it sets the cookie regardless of what is clicked.

Is there a way to set a different cookie when clicking on the Walk Away link?

Comment: @RickSmalls I noticed this `index.php?url` and `$_GET['request']` are those two supposed to be related/connected to each other? I'd need to know where the `request` is coming from as well as the `url` GET method you're using. If you have more code to show me, let me know as well as how you're using it.

Comment: @RickSmalls As for setting a different cookie name; yes I'd say you could set it inside `bummer.php` as an `else{...}` in conjunction with the `if` condition `if (!isset($_COOKIE['youwerewarned']))` so you'd do `if (!isset($_COOKIE['youwerewarned'])){...}else{ setcookie("different_name", "true", time()+6048, "/", $domain);` type of thing. What's inside `bummer.php`?

Comment: `index.php?url` is where you are redirected when you get to a the site, or any page on the site and `$_GET['request']` is supposed to be the original requested URI, from `/index.php?url=http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`. I am still learning PHP, I apologize if I am confusing everyone.

Comment: The only thing inside `bummer.php` is a link to Google that is titled **Exit**.

Comment: @RickSmalls The thing with GETs is that the `?name` should match what's being called. For instance `?request=http://$_SERVER...` try and change the `$_GET['request']` to `$_GET['url']` see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @RickSmalls Plus, the `$request` variable with the `$_GET['request']` inside it. The `$_GET['request']` needs a reference to it, such as `$_GET['request'] = "/other_page.php";` let's say, depending on what you want to do with it, which is still unclear to me. Using `$_GET['request'] = "/other_page.php";` for the `$request ="<a href='http://$domain" . $_GET['request'] . "'>";` would basically redirect to `http://www.example.com/other_page.php` if that's what the goal is. This would be for the CONTINUE link, which I've successfully tested as an example.

Comment: @RickSmalls For the Walk away page, you could delete the cookie by adding `setcookie ("youwerewarned", "", time()-3600, '/', 'example.com');` and use `page.php?request` you'll see what I mean, instead of using `page.php?url`

Comment: When you click on **Continue** a cookie is set that allows them to view the website. When you click on **Walk Away** a different cookie is set which prevents you from viewing the website and redirects to a default page.

Comment: Yes, okay, deleting cooking in the walk away page makes sense, should have thought of that. I think getting that URL to work is what I am trying to acomplish mainly.

Comment: @RickSmalls When I tried my test page being `test.php` with clicking only a link such as `test.php?url` didn't work, but `test.php?request` did. Also make sure your domain name is in the cookie deletion `setcookie ("youwerewarned", "", time()-3600, '/', 'yourdomain.com');` otherwise it may not work. Then on your LEAVE page, add `if (empty($_COOKIE)){ echo "Cookie has been deleted."; }` and you'll see for sure if the cookie's been deleted successfully.

Comment: I did as you suggested and the cookie is not deleting, and I am a little confused about the linking you re taking about.